# Не выводит случайное число в PHP

Tags: php

Почему не выводит на страницу случайное число?

*index.php*:

```
<form action="random.php" method="POST">
  <h1>Random number is <span id="rnd-num"> <?php include_once 'random.php' ?> </span></h1>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg inp-rand" placeholder="Min (not necessary)" name="min"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg inp-rand" placeholder="Max (not necessary)" name="max" />
  <p><a  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rand" role="button">Random </a> </p>
  </form>
```

*random.php*:

```
<?php 
    $min = $_POST['min'];
    $max = $_POST['max'];

    echo rand($min, $max);
 ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

При подключении [random.php](http://nowhere), `$_POST` пуст и не имеет ни `'min'`, ни `'max'`

У тега `<a>` нет атрибута *type*, поэтому клик не работает.
Вместо него можно использовать `<input type='submit'>` или `<button>Random</button>`

```html
<form action='random.php' method='POST'>
    <input placeholder='Min (not necessary)' name='min'>
    <input placeholder='Max (not necessary)' name='max'>
    <button>Random</button>
</form>
```

Воспользуемся тернарным оператором и в любом случае объявим переменную.
Через `isset` проверяем наличие `'max'` в `$_POST`.
При наличии `$max = $_POST['max']`, при отсутсвии `$max = 10`

```php
$min = isset($_POST['min']) ? $_POST['min'] : 0;
$max = isset($_POST['max']) ? $_POST['max'] : 10;

echo rand($min, $max);
```

---

Чтобы не открывать новую страницу, можно поместить всё в один документ, тогда `action` должен быть пустым, чтобы запрос вернулся на эту же страничку

<sub>[index.php](http://nowhere)</sub>

```
<?php

    $min = isset($_POST['min']) ? $_POST['min'] : 0;
    $max = isset($_POST['max']) ? $_POST['max'] : 10;

    echo "Random number is ".rand($min, $max);
?>
```

```php
<body>
    <form action='' method='POST'>
        <input placeholder='Min (not necessary)' name='min'>
        <input placeholder='Max (not necessary)' name='max'>
        <button>Random</button>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Тут две ошибки:

Потому что у вас `$min` и `$max` не заданы в момент когда форма ещё не отправлена на сервер.

В тот момент, когда показывается форма на экране, нет никаких `$_POST`, вот когда форма заполнится - тогда и будет вам `$_POST`.

Но чтобы заполнить данные и отправить форму нужно ещё нажать кнопку. А вот кнопки у вас нет. Добавьте кнопку.

```
<form action="random.php" method="POST">
  <h1>Random number is <span id="rnd-num"> <?php include_once 'random.php' ?> </span></h1>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg inp-rand" placeholder="Min (not necessary)" name="min"/>
  <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg inp-rand" placeholder="Max (not necessary)" name="max" />
  <button  type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-rand" role="button">Random </button>
  </form>
```

Ну и ещё один момент, упомяну на всякий пожарный: оба файла должны лежать в одном каталоге (ну, мало ли).

Comment: А как число, которое выпадает, показать  "<span id="rnd-num"> (вот тут) </span>", что бы при нажатии на кнопку не открывало новую страницу?

Comment: Объединить оба файла в один файл. Если установлены $_POST['min'] и  $_POST['max'] - то выводить число. Если не установлены - показывать форму (как альтернатива - форму выводить всегда, чтобы можно было ещё раз сгенерировать новое число)